# limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \ln(x^2 - y^2) $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate limit of $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)}y \ln (x^2-y^2)$
How to do that? I know, that the limit is equall to negative infinity, but how to prove that?

Comment: I think you must be restricted to $\;|x|>|y|\;$ , otherwise that logarithm isn't defined (or it is a complex logarithm, of course). By the way, choosing $\;y=0\,,\,x\to 0\;$ you get the limit is zero, so it may very well be the overall limit doesn't exist...

Comment: You say for any M, there exists an (x,y) near (0,0) such that f(x,y) is less than M.  But for some values of (x,y) in that neigborhood, f(x,y) = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $\;|x|>|y|\;$ , we can define, with principal value of angles:

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta\end{cases}\implies |\cos\theta|>|\sin\theta|\implies|\tan\theta|<1\implies -\frac\pi4<\theta<\frac\pi4\implies$$

$$y\log(x^2-y^2)=r\sin\theta\log\left[r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\right]=\sin\theta\cdot r\log\left(r^2\cos2\theta\right)=$$

$$\sin\theta\cdot \left(2r\log r+r\log\cos2\theta\right)$$

and now observe that $\;(x,y)\to(0,0)\;\implies\;r\to0\;$  , so it is now clear (with l'Hospital or otherwise) that the limit is zero.

Observe that $\;\log\cos2\theta\;$ is *well defined* all along.